# cannot convert type to expected argument type

Tags: ekeventstore

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()


// 2
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) {
case .Authorized:
  insertEvent(eventStore)
case .Denied:
  print("Access denied")
case .NotDetermined:
  // 3
  eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion:
    {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if granted {
        self!.insertEvent(eventStore)
      }
      else
      {
        print("Access denied")
      }
  })
default:
  print("Case Default")
}
```

I am getting error: cannot convert value of type '(bool,nserror!) -->void' to expected argument type 'ekeventstorerequestaccescompletionhandler'

at this line:

```
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion:
        {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove [weak self], in my case this one works:

```
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        (accessGranted: Bool, error: NSError?) in

        if accessGranted && (error == nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { completion(true) })
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { completion(false) })
        }
    })
```